# How to create a confirmation popup on exit?

Tags: uwp

How to show a confirmation popup when user tries to close the application?

And how to customize to get a dialog like in the screen?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written about this [on my blog](https://blog.mzikmund.com/2018/09/app-close-confirmation-in-uwp/) recently.

You need to subscribe to the `CloseRequested` event:

```
SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView().CloseRequested += App_CloseRequested;
```

And then use deferral to make sure the system waits for the user to confirm:

```
private async void App_CloseRequested(object sender, SystemNavigationCloseRequestedPreviewEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.GetDeferral();
    var dialog = new MessageDialog("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit");
    var confirmCommand = new UICommand("Yes");
    var cancelCommand = new UICommand("No");
    dialog.Commands.Add(confirmCommand);
    dialog.Commands.Add(cancelCommand);
    if (await dialog.ShowAsync() == cancelCommand)
    {
        //cancel close by handling the event
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Finally, you need to declare the `appCloseConfirm` capability in your `Package.appxmanifest`, as it is a restricted capability. Open `Package.appxmanifest` in XML editor and add `rescap` namespace to the `Package` element:

```
<Package ... xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
```

And then add the capability in the `<Capabilities>` element:

```
<rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose" />
```

As for the customization, you can display the UI in any way you want like using a `ContentDialog` which is fully customizable (thank you @Johnny Westlake for pointing out my error :-) ), or `Popup` or some custom UI above your app UI.

Comment: ContentDialog is fully themeable if you want, you can override it's default XAML and do whatever you want with it whilst still keeping it behaviour and flow.

Comment: Oh, didn't actually realize that it is templatable! Cool :-) . I will update the answer

Comment: I saw your guide ) and I make the popup, its work fine but I don't know how to make a custom style 4 this ) I'll wait for your update guide with custom content dialog ). thank you anyway .